# ElementTree - refer to xml node by name rather than index

Tags: xml, python-3.x, elementtree

For the xml example below (not actual xml just indicative) , for each `<field>` record I am trying to:
print out the `ref` attribute of the `title` tag and `genre` attribute of the `field` tag but only where the the `ref` attribute of the `title` tag is equal to 12. For this xml it would print out:

`12, thriller`

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<record>
  <field genre='comedy'>
      <title ref='123'>Title1</title>
      <author>Author1</author>
      <example>xml - valid xml file</example>
  </field>

  <field genre='comedy'>
       <title ref='123'>Title1</title>
       <author>Author2</author>
       <example>xml - valid xml file</example>
  </field>

   <field genre='thriller'>
       <title ref='12'>Title</title>
       <author>Author3</author>
       <example>xml - valid xml file</example>
   </field>
</record>
```

Using [Element Tree 20.5 documentation](https://docs.python.org/3/library/xml.etree.elementtree.html) I have been able to accomplish this using indexes e.g. by referring to `child[0]` rather than the `field` tag:

```
import xml.etree.ElementTree as ET
tree = ET.parse('test.xml')
root = tree.getroot()

for child in root:
    if 'ref' in child[0].attrib:
        x = child[0].get('ref')
        if x == '12':
            y = child.get('genre')
            print(x, y)
```

Whilst this does work, if for some reason there is an extra element in the xml at position `child[0]` it won't work as required.

How can I refer to it by name rather than index?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use [`find('title')`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/xml.etree.elementtree.html#xml.etree.ElementTree.Element.find) instead of `child[0]` to find child element named `title` within parent `<field>` :

```
for child in root:
    title = child.find('title')
    if 'ref' in title.attrib:
        x = title.get('ref')
        if x == '12':
            y = child.get('genre')
            print(x, y)
```

quick test: https://eval.in/893148